# Reverse proxy in golang opening too many connections towards server at higher rates

Tags: go

I have the following code

```
type transport struct {
    http.RoundTripper
}
func (t *transport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (resp *http.Response, err error) {
    resp, err = t.RoundTripper.RoundTrip(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    err = resp.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // modify response
    return resp, nil
}

// ...
proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(target)
proxy.Transport = &transport{http.DefaultTransport}
```

I have tried setting MaxConnsPerHost, this parameter works with value 2 alone, any other value it doesnt work

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too - despite its "harsh" title.

Comment: You are not closing the response bodies when ioutil.ReadAll fails.

Comment: Are you setting `MaxIdleConnsPerHost`? Is it set high enough to accommodate your expected level of concurrency? Are you connecting to multiple hosts, or just one? Do you have appropriate timeouts set to kill slow requests? Are you throttling requests at an acceptable rate? How are you using `proxy`? These are the types of things you need to show to have a [mre].

Comment: Thanks guys, MaxIdleConnsPerHost has default value of 2, i have changed it to higher value and also changed MaxIdleConns. So now no. of outgoing connections from my client are limited and reused.